# How can I get the details of postgres database using python

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm very new to this and I want to connect to postgres and get information regarding table names and keys, column details (name, length and type) in each table.

I have postgres DB configured and I'm able to connect and execute queries to it (I'm using psycopg2 module for this).
I'm looking for any python3 module to accomplish this task.
If there are any python modules can anyone please give some examples to implement this?

Comment: https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: This is nothing specific to python (assuming you already know how to make queries with your db-api connector, which is the case here), so you want to read Postgres doc to find out the (more or less db-vendor specific) way to retrieve schema informations. No need for any special module here, it's plain sql stuff.

Comment: Can you please provide some sql examples to get the informations I need? Or is there any way I can get all these configs in a .dbs file so that I can view it in DBSchema tool? I don't need any data, just the configs

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Can you please elaborate how I can accomplish the task using sqlalchemy?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/intro.html